# Combine results from two annotated queries

Tags: django, orm

I'm trying to query django in order to get the following result:

*subject_name,
total_grades,passed_grades,passed_precentage*

like

*maths,20,15,75.0*

The queries are:

```
from django.db.models import Count
passed_bysubjects = grades.objects.filter(yeardata__year="2011-2012",grade__gte=5).values('code__name').annotate(Passed=Count('grade'))
total_bysubject = grades.objects.filter(yeardata__year="2011-2012").values('code__name').annotate(Total=Count('grade'))
```

I've done as I post below, but I wonder if there is a better method.

```
results = list(total_bysubject)
for a in passed_bysubjects:
    for b in results:
        if a['code__name'] == b['code__name']:
            b['Passed'] = a['Passed']
            b['Percentaje'] = (b['Passed'])*100/b['Total']
```

Could this be achived by using django methods?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @schillingt who posted my in the right direction.

For my case the solution is:

```
qset = grades.objects.filter(
    yeardata__year="2011-2012"
).values('code__name').annotate(
    Average=Avg('grade'),
    Passed=Count('grade',filter=Q(grade__gte=5)),
    Total=Count('grade'),
    Percentaje=F('Passed')*100/F('Total')
)
```

My data is something like:

*student, code_name, year, grade*

(code_name for subject)

And I wanted to get some stats about each subject